# What's the maximum amount of accounts in a transaction?

Tags: transaction

As the title says, is there a cap to how many accounts I can access in a transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the maximum number of accounts allowed in a transaction is 64. There is a feature to increase that number to 128 at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/27241, but it has not been enabled yet.

The function that fetches the limit exists at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/e56d314df52cecc00bd8d30b56ca75adef159985/runtime/src/bank.rs#L4256, and you'll see that with that feature disabled, it returns `64`.

Answer (score 1):

> As discussed earlier, the maximum allowed size of a transaction is 1232 bytes. The size of an account address is 32 bytes. Thus, a transaction can at the very best store 35 accounts, taking into account some space for headers, signatures and other metadata.
> Blockquote

Source : https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#issues-with-legacy-transactions
PSA : this is for legacy transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is incorrect, as using LUTs we can access more than 35 accounts. Your article refers to legacy transactions, which aren't the up to date standard anymore.

Comment: yes mb , added an edit.